A sudden jump in the number of available days in the official Schengen calculator
I am trying to use the Schengen calculator to see how many days I will have left in the area after a number of visits. Here is my breakdown:

Right after the end of my stay on 8 December, I will have exactly zero days left until 10 December, which makes sense if you add all my stays starting from 14 June. However, starting from 11 December, I suddenly receive additional 10 days, even though only more day of my June stay will be disregarded. What is going on?

@jcaron That's actually perfectly normal

@Relaxed Aaah got it. it must not be read as “there’s ten days left” but “on each of the following ten days there will be one day left, so you can enter for ten days”.

@jcaron Yes, exactly!

It's perfectly normal and a result of the way the rolling period works since the Schengen Borders code was amended to counter a court case that interpreted it a bit differently. The relevant provision is in article 6:

For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay […]

Unless you once entered the Schengen area for a single day and exited on that same day, there is always a “sudden jump” in the length of authorized stay, which happens 181 days after the first relevant entry and is equal to the length of the earliest stay within the 180-day window. If that stay was a straight 90-day stay, you will go from 0 to 90 overnight.
One way to think about it is to evaluate your situation day-by-day:

On December 10, you have stayed exactly 90 days between June 14 and December 10, entry is not possible
On December 11, June 14 doesn't count anymore, you have stayed 89 days during the last 180 days (June 15 to December 11) so you can enter and stay one day
On December 12, June 15 doesn't count anymore, in spite of your stay on December 11, you have still stayed 89 days during the last 180 days and you can stay one more day
etc.

The calculator does that and finds that on all ten days between December 11 and December 20, you are allowed to stay in the Schengen area. So if you try to enter on or after December 11, you can be allowed to enter for 10 days. If you do that and leave by December 20, on December 28, you will be allowed to enter again for 8 days (or jump from 10 to 18 days) then some time at the end of January, you will get another 25 days, etc.
It's also interesting to note that from December 12 to December 17, you are only ever allowed to enter for 10 days (try it in the calculator). Days are always “released” in batches corresponding to the length of the earlier stays. The maximum stay doesn't increase gradually because you only have 88, 87, 86 and so on days within the previous 180-day period. Until later stays come into play, the maximum length of stay will always be equal to the earliest stay in the window.

@macleginn It's exactly the same logic that gives you 90 days after spending another 90 days outside the area. There is no explicit notion of discounting the first stay nor is there any special rule about 90-day stays, it's a sliding window that's refreshed every day. The calculator does take all this into account, the FAQ just provides an illustration.

The only legally binding document is the Schengen Borders code. Article 6 reads “For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay […]” The bit I highlighted is part of what was added to make it clear how the rule should be implemented.

It's because of the way rolling periods work. If you enter on the 11th of December then you start accruing days in the area but the days from your June visit continue to drop off.
